# Which is the fastest way to convert an integer to a byte array in Julia

Tags: arrays, parsing, integer, julia, hex

Question 1:Which is the fastest way to convert an integer to byte array?

```
a = 1026
aHexStr = string(a,base = 16,pad = 4) #2 bytes, 4 chars
b = zeros(UInt8,2)
k = 1
for i in 1:2:4
  b[k] = parse(UInt8,aHexStr[i:i+1],base = 16)
  k += 1
end
```

Is this method the fastest?

Related Question 2:
Which is the fastest way to convert a hexadecimal string to byte array?

I have a string of hexadecimal numbers

```
a = "ABCDEF12345678"

How can I convert this hex string to byte array?

b = zeros(UInt8,7)
k = 1
for i in 1:2:14
  b[k] = parse(UInt8,a[i:i+1],base = 16)
  k += 1
end
```

Is this method the fastest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first operation I assume that you want to keep only as many bytes as there are set in your integer, so you could do:

```
julia> a = 1026
1026

julia> [(a>>((i-1)<<3))%UInt8 for i in 1:sizeof(a)-leading_zeros(a)>>3]
2-element Vector{UInt8}:
 0x02
 0x04
```

Explanation:

- `leading_zeros(a)` get number of zero bits that `a` starts with
- `leading_zeros(a)>>3` compute number of bytes that are fully empty (`>>3` is shifitng the number by `3` bits right; in this case floor division by 8)
- `sizeof(a)-leading_zeros(a)>>3` compute number of bytes that are to be converted
- `(i-1)<<3)` compute number of bits we need to shift the index (in this case it is `i-1` times 8)
- `(a>>((i-1)<<3))%UInt8` get the `i-1`th byte of `a`

For the second operation I assume that if you have an odd number of characters we do fill the remaining part of the last byte with 0 bits + that we do not need to check if the passed data is valid:

```
julia> a = "ABCDEF12345678"
"ABCDEF12345678"

julia> function s2b(a::String)
           b = zeros(UInt8, (sizeof(a) + 1) >> 1)
           for (i, c) in enumerate(codeunits(a))
               b[(i+1)>>1] |= (c - (c < 0x40 ? 0x30 : 0x37))<<(isodd(i)<<2)
           end
           return b
       end
s2b (generic function with 1 method)

julia> s2b(a)
7-element Vector{UInt8}:
 0xab
 0xcd
 0xef
 0x12
 0x34
 0x56
 0x78
```

Both methods should be fast, but it is hard to guarantee they are fastest possible.

---

#### EDIT

Benchmarks:

```
julia> function f1(a)
           aHexStr = string(a,base = 16,pad = 4) #2 bytes, 4 chars
           b = zeros(UInt8,2)
               k = 1
           for i in 1:2:4
               b[k] = parse(UInt8,aHexStr[i:i+1],base = 16)
               k += 1
           end
           return b
       end
f1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f2(a) = [(a>>((i-1)<<3))%UInt8 for i in 1:sizeof(a)-leading_zeros(a)>>3]
f2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> a = 1026
1026

julia> @btime f1($a)
  141.795 ns (5 allocations: 224 bytes)
2-element Vector{UInt8}:
 0x04
 0x02

julia> @btime f2($a)
  29.317 ns (1 allocation: 64 bytes)
2-element Vector{UInt8}:
 0x02
 0x04

julia> function s2b(a::String)
           b = zeros(UInt8, (sizeof(a) + 1) >> 1)
           for (i, c) in enumerate(codeunits(a))
               b[(i+1)>>1] |= (c - (c < 0x40 ? 0x30 : 0x37))<<(isodd(i)<<2)
           end
           return b
       end
s2b (generic function with 1 method)

julia> a = "ABCDEF12345678"
"ABCDEF12345678"

julia> @btime hex2bytes($a)
  50.000 ns (1 allocation: 64 bytes)
7-element Vector{UInt8}:
 0xab
 0xcd
 0xef
 0x12
 0x34
 0x56
 0x78

julia> @btime s2b($a)
  48.830 ns (1 allocation: 64 bytes)
7-element Vector{UInt8}:
 0xab
 0xcd
 0xef
 0x12
 0x34
 0x56
 0x78
```

As @SundarR commented in the latter case `hex2bytes` should be used. I have forgotten that it exists.

Comment: ```
julia> a = 1026
1026

julia> [(a>>((i-1)<<3))%UInt8 for i in 1:sizeof(a)-leading_zeros(a)>>3]
2-element Vector{UInt8}:
 0x02
 0x04
```  This method is slower than the solution provided in the question.

Comment: The method s2b is faster than the code given in my question.

Comment: @Vinod Are you measuring the times with `@btime` or just `@time`? With `@btime`, the method in the answer runs about 4 times faster than the one in the question.

Comment: I am using @elapsed begin end syntax

Comment: By the way, there is a `hex2bytes` function in the Base for the second question, but that runs four to five times slower than the one here. My guess is that the difference is price paid for safety - `hex2bytes` checks that the string is even-lengthed and doesn't assume the characters are all valid hex - but it maybe worth investigating.

Comment: @Bogumil Can you explain the working of your code.

Comment: Sure - I have added explanations for the first code. Hopefully then also the second code is clearer. If not please comment.

Comment: at SundarR "@btime" will give the minimum time right.

Comment: @Vinod Yes, or you can use `@benchmark` to get the median time. The main thing is that these run the code many times, and so ensure that you're not measuring compilation time or other spurious sources of delay in the system.

Answer (score 5):

For the first question, you can `reinterpret` the bytes if you're ok with additional 0 values: `reinterpret(UInt8, [a])`.
This performs slightly faster than the code in Bogumił Kamiński's answer, by about 5-10% - but it's a difference of a few nanoseconds. So if the extra 0's are a bother, it might not be worth it.

*Edit*: You can drop the extra zeros by doing it as:

```
julia> bytesfromint(i::Int64) =
         @inbounds @view reinterpret(UInt8, [i])[1:8-leading_zeros(i)>>3]
```

This seems to be faster than the method mentioned in Bogumil Kaminsky's answer too, by 20% or so.

`@inbounds @view reinterpret(UInt8, [ai])[(8-leading_zeros(ai)>>3):-1:1]` will give you the most significant bytes first (big-endian like), or `@inbounds @view reinterpret(UInt8, [ai])[2:-1:1]` if you know your data will only take up 2 bytes.

(`@view` tells Julia to not make a copy of the part of the array we've asked for, instead indexing into the original array itself - hence avoiding the copying overhead. `@inbounds` assures Julia that our indices are within the bounds of the array - hence avoiding the bounds-checking overhead.)

Comment: I agree - this is what I would also recommend in general (but in the original question these `0`s were dropped).

Comment: reverse(reinterpret(UInt8, [a])[1:2]) will do the job for the big endian.

Comment: @Vinod See my edit. The last code segment I've mentioned (with `[2:-1:1]` indexing) runs faster than calling `reverse`.